# adicionar no arquivo Texto JAVA

Tags: java

no meu código eu queria adicionar no arquivo mas não estou conseguindo, ele sempre apaga o conteudo de antes.

```
package classejava;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import jdk.internal.jfr.events.FileWriteEvent;

public class escritor {

    public static void entraVetor(float[] vetor, int n) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            vetor[i] = entrada.nextFloat();

        }
    }

    public static void gravaArquivo(float[] vet, int n) throws IOException {

        FileWriter gravador = new FileWriter("arquivo.txt");
        BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(gravador);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            buffer.write(" " + vet[i]);
            buffer.flush();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner entrada;
        entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        float[] vet;
        int n;
        n = entrada.nextInt();
        vet = new float[n];
        entraVetor(vet, n);
        gravaArquivo(vet, n);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá.

O objeto `FileWriter` possui um construtor de dois argumentos sendo `FileWriter(File file, boolean append)` onde:

> Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object. If the second argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.

Ou seja, se você quiser adicionar conteúdo ao final do seu arquivo, você deve passar o valor `true` ao parâmetro `append` da seguinte forma:

```
FileWriter gravador = new FileWriter("arquivo.txt", true);
```